# Detach fragment not immediately

Tags: android, android-fragments, detach

I have a little question.
Currently I have a fragment.
When detaching I want to show the user something like do you want to save the changes.
But I want to call super.onDetach() after the user has selected an option. I tried to call super.onDetach() after an option but then I get an exception that super.onDetach() is not called when detaching. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

This is my code :

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {


    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                if(attachProfiel){
                    FragmentProfiel.updateProfiel();
                }
                if(attachDiagnose){
                    FragmentDiagnose.updateDiagnose();
                }
                if(attachAndere){
                    FragmentAndere.updateAndere();
                }
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Save changes?").setPositiveButton("Ja", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("Nee", dialogClickListener).show();


}
```

OnDestroyView :

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    new ExitFragment(getActivity()).show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
    super.onDestroyView();

}
```

Comment: Do you do any work in onAttach()?

Comment: No not in that fragment. But I have 3 fragments in the layout that use onAttach (To give signal to the main fragment to know if the fragment can get values or not from the 3 fragments)

Comment: Instead of onDetach() you can actually use calling your dialog fragment in onDestroyView(). This ensures the save state once your fragment gets replaced by the transaction.

Comment: Try it, and let me know if it works?

Comment: I just tried it and created an exitFragment then on OnDestroyView I call the fragment and next I do super.OnDestroyView(); . The fragment is still immediately detached. Check the post for OnDestroyView code.

Comment: What is your intention or work to be done when the Fragment detaches?

Comment: I have 3 fragments that ask some personal information. When it detaches it goes to a list with all the persons. On detaching I gather all information on the 3 fragments ( if they were attached)

Comment: How do you destroy fragment, do you use `onBackPressed()` or something else? Or is it just an OK button?

Comment: Fragment is destroyed when you press back(backstack). I have no implementation now .

Comment: Check answer I 'll publish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you call your `DialogFragment()` in `onBackPressed()` method, there by asking the user to save the preference. If you would like to reclaim the data that user entered in the fragment, then use `SharedPreference` in android. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I can't override onBackPressed in my Fragment (OnDetach instead). Using Sharedpreferences is a good idea.

Comment: Anytime, my pleasure @David

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should not go that way. This kind of mobile design is not safe. The only way to implement this is to block the Ui thread for some time until the user presses something in dialog or a fixed time expires. But then presume that while the app blocks the user gets a phone call or even worse the phone call comes in when the dialog is about to show. It would be a nightmare.

best way to approach this is to periodically (temp)save state of screen and then ask you that he has unsaved changes in the onresume of next fragment or activity.  For things to run smoothly android does need to be able to shut down your app whenever it needs to. If you try to circumvent that control then its a ugly mess ahead.